# Is it possible for JME app to modify default form on your mobile?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I have been asked to find out if its possible to modify the default screen on a mobile phone with jme. Basically the screen that the phone shows when its on but doing nothing but which usually shows the network and nearest tower info.

My understanding of JME is that this is not possible. One would have to use symbian for this or some older protocol like USSD?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the default screen of a device with J2ME. You need a native application (Symbian, Windows Mobile) to do so. J2ME lays in a sandboxed environment and has many restrictions on what you can access. An application can only be started by the user and can't run as a service. It is also not possible to register an application to run at the start-up of the phone.

It has been discussed that MIDP 3.0 may address many of the above issues, but I don't think it will ever be available.

Answer (score 0):

From an application lifecycle point of view, there are ways to approximate what you are trying to do but they almost unvariably require handset manufacturer support.

If you have a choice, the Sony Ericsson JP8 platform has non-standard extensions to JavaME that can help.

Accessing telephony information, however will be a major issue. Look for a handset that implements the cbs protocol of JSR-120, it could prove useful.

Accessing the phone idle/standby/main  screen on Series60 (Symbian) phones will require nokia support too, BTW.